# android ndk so sometime crash SIGILL(ILL_ILLOPC) Illegal Opcode

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

thanks for help,this confuse me

use opencv process image sometimes

crash at code CvSparseMat::copyToSparseMat(cv::SparseMat&)

Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0x723e7d51fc (*pc=00000000)
x0 000000723eb0fc38 x1 000000723eb0cb58 x2 0000007fe1557ca8 x3 0000007360ca9200
x4 00000072d37c8980 x5 00000072d37c894e x6 61642f617461642f x7 6a2e6d6f632f6174
x8 000000736415a5a0 x9 000000000000000a x10 000000000000001f x11 0000000000000028
x12 61637362696c2f73 x13 6f732e62696c2d6e x14 be41013c00000000 x15 617267696e6a6269
x16 0000000000000000 x17 000000736407b094 x18 00000067ee680000 x19 0000007360ca9200
x20 00000073640487b2 x21 000000723ead40e0 x22 0000000000000000 x23 0000007364043d83
x24 000000736404d69b x25 000000736415a000 x26 000000736415a5a8 x27 0000000000000036
x28 000000723e2fcfac x29 000000680a5f95f0
sp 000000680a5f95a0 lr 0000007364093bac pc 000000723e7d51fc

caused by:
SIGILL(ILL_ILLOPC) Illegal Opcode